# The matplotlib ticker FuncFormatter

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to manually set the ticker for a bar plot. I am using the FunFormatter function. Yet, I found that the behavior of the FunFormmater is too strange. For X-axis range from 0 to 91, I found that the FunFormmater returns the following ... Any idea how does it work.
Here is the [link for the data file](https://app.box.com/s/j6d7vosgkrgoxfjro49qlgpng9ug97ln)
Thanks in advance

-10.0
0.0
10.0
20.0
30.0
40.0
50.0
60.0
70.0
80.0
90.0
100.0
28.805725806451605
38.374395161290316
41.22463709677419
47.128709677419344
48.55383064516128
49.36818548387095
51.20048387096774
52.42201612903225
53.439959677419345
53.439959677419345
53.03278225806451
53.643548387096764
56.08661290322579
59.75120967741935
64.63733870967741
70.54141129032257
76.85266129032257
83.16391129032257
95.58282258064514

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as p
import matplotlib.mlab as m
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

file1=np.load('numofdays.npz')
fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=1)
ax=axes
x=np.arange(len(file1['arr_0']))
y=np.array(file1['arr_0'])
ax.bar(x,y)
mydates=p.DatetimeIndex(file1['arr_1'])

def mme(xx,pos=None):
    print(xx)
#    print(mydates[int(xx-9)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    return mydates[int(xx-9)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mme))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: What is strange about those numbers? Note that you have a lot more information than we have, e.g. access to the data, an idea about the desired outcome etc. See [mcve] for what is needed to help here. From the information provided until now, one can deduce that you have a dataset of around 100 rows and hence the Formatter will format some numbers in the range 0 to 100. This seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I attached the data file. Any idea why those number starts with -10. Also, the script doesn't work if I replace the int(xx-9) with int(xx) on the mme function.

Comment: I suppose the first (invisible) tick on the axis is at -10. Can you also say what exactly you are trying to achieve? In your own words, how should the axis look like at the end?

Comment: My data is grided on uneven time, so I am trying to set my time manually. That is why I am using FuncFormatter function. I expected that I will see my time x-axis starts at the first time which is 1982-01-02, yet it starts at 2006-01-04. Also, the last point is at 2011-12-21, yet I found that the last data is at 2009-04-02.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit dangerous to show only every tenth label for *un*equally spaced data, because you don't know what happens in between.

However to get your script running, you will of course need to make sure the position `xx` is a valid index of the array. E.g. the position `100` is not valid, because your array only has 92 elements. To this end you may just introduce a condition.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as p

import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

file1=np.load('data/numofdays.npz')

fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=1)

x=np.arange(len(file1['arr_0']))
y=np.array(file1['arr_0'])
ax.bar(x,y)
mydates=p.DatetimeIndex(file1['arr_1'])

def mme(xx,pos=None):
    if int(xx) in x:
        return mydates[int(xx)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        return ""

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mme))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As an alternative, I would definitely consider plotting the actual dates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as p

file1=np.load('data/numofdays.npz')

fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=1)

y=np.array(file1['arr_0'])

mydates = p.DatetimeIndex(file1['arr_1'])

ax.bar(mydates,y, width=60)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ... it really helped me.